# How to distribute ssl private keys for nodejs https module

Tags: node.js, security, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use the `https` module for my nodejs server. I have the certificate and intermediate CA certificates in my repository, as they are public. However, I do not know how to store and distribute the certificate's private key, which I need to instantiate the server. I am using elastic beanstalk to deploy my code, so generating certs on the host machine won't work (at least I don't think so).

Answer (score 0):

You do not distribute this private key, you keep it secret !
Only you have access to the server and the private key, your clients have the public key and they will encrypt their data with it. Your server will be able to decrypt these data with the private key (which, once again, is secret)